# Is there a way to bypass basic authentication in an Excel query?

Tags: excel, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, excelquery

I have an excel file, I get data from web, using API. My data returns in json format.
I schedule my query in 'query' and 'properties' so the data updates frequently.

I need to be able to share my file with people around my company, but when they try to refresh it they hit the 'access web content' window which requires them to input credentials, for either 'anonymous', 'windows', 'basic', 'web api' or 'organizational account.

I am using 'basic' with a generic reporting email address and API token as password.

Here is the first line of my m code:
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("**website**" & "**filter**", [Headers=[Accept="application/json"]])),

I have tried to embed authorization and encoded credentials in format username:password like so:
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("**website**" & "**filter**", [Headers=[Accept="application/json",authorization="basic username:password]])),

I keep getting a stack overflow issue.

I have read up so much online, and no methods I can see work for me. I'm quite new to this and not sure what other ways I could try. I need to bypass asking my colleagues for credentials, and not rely on my machine to push new data into the sheet, as I'm not always online.

once I have the data, I will analyse it using power pivot, so my colleagues can see an overview any time.

I can't use the jira excel add-in as not everyone has the add-in, and I cant ask them to download it as that would be too complicated for them.

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's perfectly fine to embed your basic credentials in the m code, but then you have to change your access web content permission creds to 'anonymous'.

go to query tab>edit>data source settings>edit permissions> under credentials type: select anonymous.