# Why does my excel query return a stack overflow for some people and not others?

Tags: excel, stack-overflow, powerpivot, jira-rest-api, excelquery

I have a power pivot excel dashboard with pivot charts. I obtain the data by using the jira REST API to the source, and the query is scheduled.

I have tested access to the dashboard with my colleagues. For 2 people it returns a stack overflow error when trying to get data from source. And others it's absolutely fine and gets the data on the schedule.

Why would it return a stack overflow error for some and not others?

Comment: Do they have lots of pages open in their browser IE Chrome or whatever?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I really appreciate it as I'm really stuck with this one as it's not my realm! It could be this, I will have to check. Could there be any other things that I could look out for too? Also, would you mind explaining how these things would effect my report, so I can understand better and look for them in the future. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was an issue as my credentials are embedded in the m code, but then  users needed to have 'anonymous' selected for the credentials type. If it wasn't set to anonymous, users return stack overflow.

go to query tab>edit>data source settings>edit permissions> under credentials type: select anonymous.

Once you have set it once, it remembers for next time, however I'm trying to find a way that it will remember in the file itself instead of for each user, as I'll have to assist each user to select the anonymous credential type.

Link to supported method: [Is there a way to bypass basic authentication in an Excel query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66549380/is-there-a-way-to-bypass-basic-authentication-in-an-excel-query)